# Mongo/Mongoose - Count of empty double nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
var RowSchema = new Schema({
  value: String,
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
});

var ColumnSchema = new Schema({
  rows: [RowSchema],
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
});

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    'default': shortid.generate
  },
  name: String,
  columns: [ColumnSchema],
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
})
```

I want to run a query to find all `Item`'s that contain zero rows in **all** columns. So I know how to find an array that is empty:

```
Item.find({ columns: { $exists: true, $eq: [] } })
```

But I want something like

```
Item.find({ 'columns.rows': { $exists: true, $eq: [] } })
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Item.find({ 'columns.rows': {$in: [] } })
```